# How to remove a specific attribute while write to XML in PySpark

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is the sample XML where the attribute "Value" is Blank under AdditionalAttribute.
    How I can remove this attribute while writting into XML in pyspark. I want to remove only if the attribute is blank.

```
<ItemList>
    <Item Action="MANAGE" ItemGroupCode="PROD" ItemID="Item1" OrganizationCode="" UnitOfMeasure="EACH">
        <PrimaryInformation Description="Item1" ItemType="WEB" ProductLine="GM" IsPickupAllowed="Y" IsReturnable="Y" IsShippingAllowed="Y" ShortDescription="Item1:Black:Medium" IsModelItem="N" ModelItemUnitOfMeasure="EACH" ImageLocation="" ImageID=""></PrimaryInformation>
        <ItemAliasList Reset="Y"></ItemAliasList>
        <Extn ExtnColor="BLACK" ExtnColorDesc=""></Extn>
        <ClassificationCodes Model="Item1"></ClassificationCodes>
        <AdditionalAttributeList Reset="Y">
            <AdditionalAttribute AttributeDomainID="ItemAttribute" AttributeGroupID="ItemAttributeGroup1" Name="Size" Value=""></AdditionalAttribute>
            <AdditionalAttribute AttributeDomainID="ItemAttribute" AttributeGroupID="ItemAttributeGroup1" Name="Color" Value=""></AdditionalAttribute>
        </AdditionalAttributeList>
    </Item>

</ItemList>

I tried with setting treatEmptyValuesAsNulls to true while writing. But it doesn't work.

 df.write \
    .format('xml') \
    .options(rowTag='Item', rootTag='ItemList', treatEmptyValuesAsNulls = 'true') \
    .save(path)

Any kind of help is appreciated.
```

Comment: I have solution in BeautifulSoup

Comment: Hi, But I need solution in Pyspark.

Comment: @Tapan. I am sorry as pyspark is heavy to download and I don't have knowledge of it